# Trouble while moving a data from one to another using File Handling in Java

Tags: java, file

To provide some context, I am writing code in Java to move data from one file to another using File Handling. The files are named in the following format: "form+stream.txt". The form is equivalent to a student's grade, so for instance if he is grade-12 then his form is SC, whereas the Stream is equivalent to section, which could be 1,2,3,4 or 5. So if a student is in grade-11 and section 5, his data will be stored in a file named "S5.txt". The following code shows all the variables of the Student Class:

```
class Student
{   
public int school_number;
String surname;
String first_name;
String current_board;
String form;
int stream;
String house;
int late_mark;
int absent_mark;
int present_mark; 
//methods of Student class
 }
```

This information is stored in a Text file in the following format:

School Number

First Name

Surname

Current Board

Form

Stream

House

Late Mark

Absent Mark

Present Mark

---

Now suppose I want to change the Form of any particular student, I can easily do that by creating another Text File. However, the problem in this case is that by changing the form of the student I would have to move him to another file because if you recall, I mentioned that the Students are added to files according to their stream/section and Form. Therefore I would have to first delete the student from the existing file and add him to a file, which is based on a new combination of his form and stream. To do this I used the following code:

```
 System.out.println("Welcome");
System.out.println();
System.out.println("Please enter the School Number of the Student whose   Information you would like to change");//Since school number is Unique
int x=Integer.parseInt(bw.readLine());
  int test=0;
    for(int i=0;i<30;i++)
      for(int j=0;j<100;j++)
      {  if(a[i][j]!=null)
 // This array is reads all the student information from the text files and creates objects of student type.
        {

        if(this.a[i][j].school_number==x)
        {    
            System.out.println("The Previous Entry of the Form was: "+this.a[i][j].form);
            System.out.println("Please enter the new Form");
            String w=this.bw.readLine();
            Student q=new Student();
            String num="";
            num=num.valueOf(x);
            if(w.equals("SC")||w.equals("S")||w.equals("A")||w.equals("B")||w.equals("C")||w.equals("D")) //Checking whether the input is valid or not.
            {
            //Making Changes to the File
            File f=new File("Temp.txt");
            f.createNewFile();
            String v="";
            v=v.valueOf(this.a[i][j].stream);
            String u=this.a[i][j].form;
            BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new FileReader(u+v+".txt")); //Form+Stream as I mentioned earlier
            BufferedWriter bw=new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("Temp.txt"));
            String a=br.readLine();
            while(a!=null)//Writing Data to Temp File
            { bw.write(a);
              bw.newLine();
              a=br.readLine();
            }
            br.close();
            bw.close();
            BufferedReader br1=new BufferedReader(new FileReader("Temp.txt"));
            BufferedWriter bw1=new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(u+v+".txt"));
            String b=br1.readLine();
            while(b!=null)
           {  if(b.equals(num))// Deleting the student from the previous file
               {  bw1.write("*"); //I didn't know what else to write
                 bw1.newLine();
                 String z1=br1.readLine();
                 if(z1.equals(this.a[i][j].first_name))
                 bw1.write("*");
                 bw1.newLine();
                 String z2=br1.readLine();
                 if(z2.equals(this.a[i][j].surname))
                 bw1.write("*");
                 bw1.newLine();
                 String z3=br1.readLine();
                 if(z3.equals(this.a[i][j].current_board))
                 bw1.write("*");
                 bw1.newLine();
                 String z4=br1.readLine();
                 if(z4.equals(this.a[i][j].form))
                 bw1.write("*");
                 bw1.newLine();
                 String z5=br1.readLine();
                 int q0=Integer.parseInt(z5);
                 if(q0==this.a[i][j].stream)
                 bw1.write("*");
                 bw1.newLine();
                 String z6=br1.readLine();
                 if(z6.equals(this.a[i][j].house))
                 bw1.write("*");
                 bw1.newLine();
                 String z7=br1.readLine();
                 int q1=Integer.parseInt(z7);
                 if(q1==this.a[i][j].late_mark)
                 bw1.write("*");
                 bw1.newLine();
                 String z8=br1.readLine();
                 int q2=Integer.parseInt(z8);
                 if(q2==this.a[i][j].absent_mark)
                 bw1.write("*");
                 bw1.newLine();
                 String z9=br1.readLine();
                 int q3=Integer.parseInt(z9);
                 if(q3==this.a[i][j].present_mark)
                 bw1.write("*");
              }
                else
                bw1.write(b);
                bw1.newLine();
                b=br1.readLine();
            }
            bw1.close();
            br1.close();
            BufferedReader br2=new BufferedReader(new FileReader("Temp.txt"));
            String g="";
            g=g+w;
            int h=this.a[i][j].stream;
            String hh="";
            hh=hh.valueOf(h);
            String new_file=g+hh;
            BufferedWriter bw2=new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(new_file+".txt",true));
            String bb=br2.readLine();
            while(bb!=null&&!(bb.equals("")))//Adding data to the new File.
            { if(bb.equals(num))
                {bw2.newLine();
                 bw2.write(bb);
                 bw2.newLine();
                 String z1=br2.readLine();
                 if(z1.equals(this.a[i][j].first_name))
                 bw2.write(z1);
                 bw2.newLine();
                 String z2=br2.readLine();
                 if(z2.equals(this.a[i][j].surname))
                 bw2.write(z2);
                 bw2.newLine();
                 String z3=br2.readLine();
                 if(z3.equals(this.a[i][j].current_board))
                 bw2.write(z3);
                 bw2.newLine();
                 String z4=br2.readLine();
                 if(z4.equals(this.a[i][j].form))
                 bw2.write(w);
                 bw2.newLine();
                 String z5=br2.readLine();
                 int q0=Integer.parseInt(z5);
                 if(q0==this.a[i][j].stream)
                 bw2.write(z5);
                 bw2.newLine();
                 String z6=br2.readLine();
                 if(z6.equals(this.a[i][j].house))
                 bw2.write(z6);
                 bw2.newLine();
                 String z7=br2.readLine();
                 int q1=Integer.parseInt(z7);
                 if(q1==this.a[i][j].late_mark)
                 bw2.write(z7);
                 bw2.newLine();
                 String z8=br2.readLine();
                 int q2=Integer.parseInt(z8);
                 if(q2==this.a[i][j].absent_mark)
                 bw2.write(z8);
                 bw2.newLine();
                 String z9=br2.readLine();
                 int q3=Integer.parseInt(z9);
                 if(q3==this.a[i][j].present_mark)
                 bw2.write(z9);
                 bb=br2.readLine();
                }
                else
                bb=br2.readLine();
            }
            bw2.close();
            br2.close();
            f.delete();
            test=1;
        }
    }
}
}
if(test==1)
System.out.println("Change Successful!");
if(test==0)
    {
        System.out.println("Student not found in DATABASE. Would you like to add student?");
    }
}  
}
}
```

This code is not working properly and is producing erroneous results. The star pattern is appearing on the original file, which I believe is good news, however the last block of the code which deals with writing new data to the file is not working. The new text file, which is supposed to have information is appearing to be blank withs spaces. What mistake have I made? Please help

PS: Sorry for the length of the question and please do tell me if any more information regarding the code is needed.

Thank You.

Comment: Is moving from txt-Files to a DB an Option? You could dump the txt Files from DB when changes occur if 3rd party systems need them. Are other applications going to change those files?

Comment: @Fildor, thank you for replying. To be honest, I am still a beginner and I don't know what DB stands for. Could you please elaborate on your point?

Comment: DB = Database. I mean a real database like MySQL, SQLite, or if you like some NoSQL-DB ... Holding all that data in txt files is really ... well you are already running into issues. At least you should use some better (and well-known) format so you could serialize / deserialize easily into objects. Like XML or JSON.